# HTML caching on Coveo Hive components

Tags: coveo

Is it possible to implement HTML caching for `Coveo Hive components`, similar to how we apply caching to Sitecore components using parameters like 'Vary by (`user, query string, etc.`)'?

Our goal is to reduce the number of queries to Coveo.

Answer (score 0):

The Coveo Hive components have been designed with HTML caching in mind and most of the components are **"cached by data source"**, which should be enough in most cases. The rendered HTML depends solely on the data source parameter values, i.e. for a given set of parameters the HTML will always be the same regardless of the current visitor or the viewing page.

Note that the **Context component is an exception** and **can't be cached** as its purpose is to render all the non-cacheable information to make the HTML caching work for other components. Once the page is rendered, all the cached components can access the context on the client-side such as the current item, visitor details etc. and do their job as expected.